# How to update data changes in an already drawn SPSS graph

Tags: charts, spss

I have drawn several bar chart, scatter, and line graphs in SPSS 21 and spent lots of time on editing their look. But, I realized that I made some mistakes in data and they are already changed. In Microsoft excel, graphs are interactive/dynamic, meaning that they change if you modify the values of each cell. Can we mimic the same feature in SPSS 21? Is there any way I can update graphs without redrawing them from the scratch? I have saved them as output, but when I load them no change is reflected and the graphs are associated with old data.

I have saved syntaxes to produce the graphs, but when I run the syntax, the graphs are produced in standard looking that need lots of changes to look good. When I save chart templates and apply them to new charts, they don't look the same meaning that some of the changes are not applied.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. I feel you with making all the changes and the inconsistency in applying chart templates though. A few tips to mitigate this in the future are;

- Do everything you can with GGRAPH and inline GPL statements to get the look of the chart close to how you want it.
- Start with a chart template that is closer to your typical end goals. (See [here](http://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/hacking-the-default-spss-chart-template/) on how to make some simple edits to the default template).

Some things are still difficult to fully automate like label placement in the chart. These simple tips though get me very close to the end goal, and only rarely do I need to take the time to polish a chart with editing post-hoc.

Comment: thanks @Andy, yes it is unnecessarily painful and tiring. Your tips are valuable to peers. Many thanks. I wait for a while for others and then decide on which answer to accept.